# Eigenvalues of an $n$-path

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory, graph-laplacian

> Show that the eigenvalues of the Laplacian matrix of an $n$-path graph are $$ 2 - 2 \cos \left( \frac{i\pi}{n} \right), \qquad i=0,1,\dots,n-1$$

---

I know that the characteristic polynomial of the Laplacian of the $n-$path satisfies

$$\chi_n(x)=x\chi_{n-1}(x)-\chi_{n-2}(x)$$

and thus $\chi_n(x) = U_n(x/2)$ is a Chebyshev polynomial of second kind because Chebyshev's polynomials of second kind satisfy the recurrence:

$$U_n(x) = 2xU_{n-1}(x)-U_{n-2}(x)$$

Wiki says $U_n(x)$ has roots $\cos\left (\frac{i\pi}{n+1}\right ), i=1,..,n$. Thus the roots of $\chi_n(x) = U_n(x/2)$ are $2\cos\left (\frac{i\pi}{n+1}\right )$ and so am wondering where the additional $2$ is coming from? Thanks.

Comment: Having the same general 2nd order recurrence is one thing ; but have you checked that the first two initial polynomials are the same ?

Comment: @JeanMarie Yes, they are the same, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with what $n$-path is, but the Laplacian with the eigenvalues $2-2\cos(i\pi/n), i=0,\ldots,n-1$ is the matrix of order $n$ of the form,

\begin{bmatrix}
1&-1\\
-1&2&-1\\
&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots\\
&&-1&2&-1\\
&&&-1&1
\end{bmatrix}

Comment: If this corresponds to your question, then it can be shown recursively or using the corresponding eigenvectors. This matrix belongs to the $\tau_{11}$-algebra; see Bozzo & Di Fiori 1995.

Comment: Yes, that is the matrix whose eigenvalues I am looking at. $n-$path is just a straight line path of $n$ vertices. May I know how you got those eigenvalues for that matrix? Thanks.

Comment: You can look in Bozzo and Di Fiori "ON THE USE OF CERTAIN MATRIX ALGEBRAS ASSOCIATED WITH DISCRETE TRIGONOMETRIC TRANSFORMS IN MATRIX DISPLACEMENT DECOMPOSITION"   also the pure Neumann case on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors_of_the_second_derivative

Comment: You have a proof here, from a PDE viewpoint: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors_of_the_second_derivative#Neumann_case

Comment: If not clear how the proof applies: 1) set $h=1$.  2) Multiply everything with $-1$. 3) $4\sin^2(x/2)=2-2\cos(x)$.