# Closed form of the eigenvalues of a specific tridiagonal matrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, closed-form, graph-laplacian, tridiagonal-matrices

Hello I would like to know if someone has an idea of how to compute the eigenvalues (in a closed form) of the following matrix in order to implement it for fast calculations.

The matrix is the following :

- the diagonal is {1, 2, 2, …, 2, 2, 1} (twos everywhere except first and last row)
- The super diagonal  and sub diagonal are {-1, -1, …, -1}

I would like to know the eigenvalues whatever the dimension of the matrix.

I don’t even know if there exist a closed form for the eigenvalues of this problem but somehow i imagine that there are some geniuses out there that could find it.

Thanks to all in advance for any idea you could give !

NB the matrix for $n=4$ looks like: (where $n$ denotes the dimension of the matrix)

$$\left(\begin{array}{rrrr}1&-1&0&0\\
-1&2&-1&0\\
0&-1&2&-1\\
0&0&-1&1\end{array}\right)$$

Comment: Note that your matrix, lets call it $A$, will be symmetric semi-definite positive. That is because we can express $x^t Ax$ as the sum $\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} (x_{i+1}-x_i)^2$ which is zero iff $x_1=x_i$ for all $i$ and is always non-negative. This lets you prove that your matrix will admit a basis of orthonormal eigenvectors each corresponding to a non-negative real valued eigenvalue.

Comment: Also note that $v=(1,\cdots, 1)$ is an eigenvector in the nucleus. The rest of the eogenvectors can be obtained to be orthogonal to this one, that is we can obtain a basis of egenvectors including $v$ for which the coordinates of the other eigenvectors add up to $0$.

Comment: See Theorem 2.1 in this [document](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/144007447.pdf) with a=0, b=1.

Comment: Isn't this the Laplacian of a [path graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_graph)?

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4128143/339790)

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3434292/339790)

Comment: @JeanMarie the paper by da Fonseca assumes $a>0.$ Then the matrices are invertible, whicht is not the case in the present question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us refer to [this paper](https://www.emis.de/journals/AMEN/2005/040903-7.pdf) by Wen-Chyuan Yueh.
The general form of the studied matrices  is
\begin{equation}
  A = \begin{pmatrix} 
     -\alpha +b & c & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & 0 \\
     a & b & c & 0 & \dots & 0 & 0 \\
     0 & a & b & c & \dots & 0 & 0 \\
     \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots &\ddots & \vdots & \vdots\\
     0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & a & -\beta + b
  \end{pmatrix},\tag 1
\end{equation}
where $\;a,b,c,\alpha,\beta\in \mathbb{C}, ac\neq 0.$
In your matrices $a=c=-1, b=2, \alpha=\beta=1.$

Theorem $4$ in the referenced paper gives explicit form of eigenvalues when  $\alpha=\beta=\sqrt{ac}\neq 0,$
$$\lambda_k=b+2\sqrt{ac}\cos\frac{k\pi}{n},\quad n=1,2,3,\dots, n.$$

This is exactly what your matrices satisfy.

Comment: Thank you so much, I am new to this community, you are incredible guys !

Comment: @user1378851 you're welcome. I am glad I could help. If you find my answer useful, please accept it (green bouton).

Comment: I did’nt know for the green button,  i just did !